# How To Halt All Threads If There Is No Internet Connection

Tags: ios, xcode, networking, swift

The problem:

My app sometimes needs to run API calls to my server. However, if the user does not have an internet connection the app crashes because nothing gets returned. I have built a function called **connection** that returns true if the user has an internet connection.

So how do I use this and when I run the **runAPI** method, check for connection first and if there isn't any than halt all threads and present a view that says "No Internet Connection" so the user knows he has to fix his/her connection.

Please keep in mind that other classes are calling the **runAPI** method in this class. So say Class XYZ calls the **runAPI** method which is located in Class API. So if there is no connection I want to abandon everything that is going on and just simply present that "No Internet Connection" view.

```
func runAPI(request: String) -> NSDictionary {
    return parseJSON(getJSON(request))
}

func runAPIArray(request: String) -> NSArray {
    return parseJSONArray(getJSON(request))
}

func getJSON(urlToRequest: String) -> NSData{
    return NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: urlToRequest))
}

func parseJSON(inputData: NSData) -> NSDictionary{
    var error: NSError?
    var boardsDictionary: NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(inputData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &error) as NSDictionary
    return boardsDictionary
}

func parseJSONArray(inputData: NSData) -> NSArray{
    var error: NSError?
    var boardsArray: NSArray = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(inputData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &error) as NSArray
    return boardsArray
}

func connection() -> Bool {
    var reach = Reachability.reachabilityForInternetConnection()
    var networkStatus = reach.currentReachabilityStatus()
    return networkStatus != NetworkStatus.NotReachable
}
```

Comment: I do not believe this will work reliably because you can't predict what state a request will be in at the moment you decide to stop the threads (or, more accurately, the operations that the threads are performing).  Usually, if there's a network problem, the requests will time out and all you need to do is handle the resulting error.  You would be better to treat nothing being returned as a reasonable event and fix the crash.

Comment: Why not use the built-in NSURLConnectionDelegate methods to detect when a connection fails due to a down connection? The 'connection:didFailWithError:' [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSURLConnectionDelegate/connection:didFailWithError:) will throw you an error that will let you know a bit better. [Error Codes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003793-CH3g-SW40)

Answer (score 3):

> However, if the user does not have an internet connection the app crashes because nothing gets returned.

Then you have a bug. Just because you have a connection doesn't mean you'll get something back. Just because you get something back doesn't mean it'll be complete or legal. (You could easily lose the connection in the middle of a request.) There is no kind of network response that should crash you. Your code must be resilient against that.

If the network response fails (for any of many reasons), then you should deal with that failure. When network reachability indicates you have no connection, you should display your "No Connection" UI. These are completely separate issues.

Keep in mind that Network Reachability is very limited. It basically indicates that the system would *try* to connect to the server if you asked it to. It in no way promises that the connection would successful. There could be a firewall in the way. The server could be down. The service could fail to respond. Only making the request can tell you if the request would succeed.

Answer (score 0):

Why not wrap the whole thing in an if/else?
pseudocode, but:

```
if (connection() == YES)
{
  hit API;
  do whatever;
}
else
{
  UIAlertView = "app requires internet conn";
}
```

That way you wont risk crashing out

Comment: What if the connection dies in the middle of the request?

Comment: I could use more information as to the high level overview of what youre trying to accomplish. I'd say you can wrap the internet dependent section in a try/catch block. that way at least it won't crash out. If you are retrieving a GET from the api, i dont see how the internet connection could realistically fail halfway through if you test it right before hitting the api

Comment: @sandman0615 A connection could fail for many reasons as stated in Rob's answer. You should never assume something will just work, especially in spotty reception areas etc. What is to say that the API does not return a large amount of data, if that transfer is happening over a slow connection (say it takes 5 seconds to complete) a lot can happen in that amount of time.

Comment: Absolutely. If there are a moderate number of requests, it is almost *certain* that some of them will fail in the middle over the time the app is in use (and only one has to fail). Try/Catch isn't the answer here (that's not even possible in Swift). Avoid crashing in the first place by validating data before trusting it.

Comment: Thats true, i was making assumptions. Thats why i asked for a more high level overview. Where specifically does it crash in the code? or does it just hang on d/c